# Categories and subcategories mod rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have this code as an example for a subcategory url,

the file is `subcategory.php`

The link to the url is like this:

```
 <a href="store/subcategory.php?catid=guitars&subcatid=electrics"></a>
```

and the htaccess rule so far is

```
RewriteRule ^store/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ subcategory.php?catid=$1&subcatid=$2 [L]
```

As a result i want accomplish this,
Turn this url:

```
www.mysite.com/store/subcategory.php?catid=guitars&subcatid=electrics
```

into

```
www.mysite.com/store/guitars/electrics
```

How can i do this? What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subcategory\.php\?catid=([^\s&]+)&subcatid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /store/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^store/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ subcategory.php?catid=$1&subcatid=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, i think is the correct answer, however, since i also have the store.php file ( www.mysite.com/store )as an index only for this section of my website (where all products are listed), using your code loads the page but without the proper styles

Comment: css/js etc is due to your use of relative paths. You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You did your html wrong. The ONLY urls that should ever appear in client-side html are the "pretty" ones:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/store/guitars/electrics">
```

That means your mod_rewrite is useless, because the URL the client is sending to your server is already the ugly one. You should generate pretty urls when you build the page.